# Google Compute Engine - MongoDB Cluster in European Zone/Region

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine

Google allows users to create a MongoDB cluster using "Click-To-Deploy" on Google Compute Engine Solutions. With this, it is only possible to create the cluster within the US zone (any of the 3 regions), but not in an European region.

Can anybody tell me where I find deployment templates/help to set up the instances for a cluster in the European zone? Or did I miss something crucial?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have access to EU because, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading) you don't have a "Premier" account.  Normally to deploy to EU ONLY, you need to fill out the [following form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1W7LsnYRj0eBAzEQlDtFbsVuIZ0nFU2TaP7cZiaY4Z0Q/viewform?formkey=dDllb3FHLS1IdXVIcjVKR3FScklka1E6MQ).

Once you have that form filled and your App is located in Europe only, I guess you will be able to deploy a cluster to it

Comment: As far as I understand, this is just for the app engine, not for a cluster within the compute engine. But thanks for you help.